# Writing to ram - LINUX

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, system-calls, ram

I am wondering if always when we write data to ram we are entering
kernel mode? I can't think of a scenario where we can write data to
ram without any system-call which will provoke the kernel mode.

Is there a way to write data to ram without any system-call or entering
kernel mode in general and staying in user mode?

Also, the same question for just accessing ram data. Is there a way to access data stored on ram staying in user mode?

Comment: Are you asking about normal memory accesses (where kernel maps memory into a process' virtual address space and after that has happened the process can read/write to it without kernel doing anything more); or are you asking about something "less normal", like the `/dev/mem` pseudo device (that is a security disaster resulting from poor design decisions)?

Comment: @Brendan I'm asking if in general every time you write to ram the operating system switching to kernel mode or not?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think so, is it proves I can write to ram without the system switching to kernel mode?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, for access RAM (for read or write) you don't need system calls.